# Rate of price depreciation

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

The rate of depreciation $\frac{dV}{dt}$ of a machine is inversely proportional to the square of $(t+1)$, where V is the value of the machine $t$ years after it was purchased.The initial value of the machine is $500,000$ and its value decreased $ 100,000$ in the first year. Estimate the value after four years.

The function is 
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{K}{(t+1)^2} $$

We can integrate with respect to $t$, which is time, and get
$$V(t)=-\frac{K}{t+1}+C$$
We also know the values at $V(0)$ and $V(1)$ which are
$$V(0)=500,000$$
$$V(1)=400,000$$
Now setting up the equation for each value gives us
$$V(0)=500,000= -\frac{K}{1}+C$$
$$V(1)=400,000=-\frac{K}{2}+C $$
I have solved this equation before and gotten $K=-200,000$ and $C=300,000$
but I cannot remember how I arrived at these answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the top equation and subtract the bottom one for:

$$100,000=-\frac{K}{2} \implies K=-200,000.$$

Then just sub back into the top equation:

$$500,000=-\frac{-200,000}{1}+C$$
$$500,000=200,000+C \implies C=300,000.$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the second equation by $2$, you have the pair of equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
-K & + C &= 500~000 \\
-K & +2C &= 800~000
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Substracting the first from the second, we get $C=300~000$. Then we only have to calculate (using the first equation)
$$
K = C - 500~000 = -200~000
$$
It's that easy.

Answer (score 0):

rearranging we can get:
$$K=C-500,000$$
$$K=2(C-400,000)$$
now making them equal we get:
$$-800,000+C=-500,000$$
and so:
$$C=300,000$$
now we want to substitute this back into one of the original equations:
$$K=(300,000)-500,000=-200,000$$